# SyntaxError: '[object HTMLDocument]' is not a valid selector in firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

To load my local js lib and run an alert command.

```
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "http://127.0.0.1/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
$(document).ready(function(){
alert("hello world");
});
```

1.In chrome's inspect--console
Pop up a window with `hellow world`,no problem.

2.in firefox's console.
It run into an error as below:

```
SyntaxError: '[object HTMLDocument]' is not a valid selector
```

Why the code snippet can't run in firefox's console?

Comment: The dev tools provide a **Network** tab. Please confirm: Is the resource `http://127.0.0.1/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js` _found_ (e.g. HTTP 200 response)? If not, which _actual URL_ is requested? `$` isn’t jQuery in your case, but the `document.querySelector` alias available in the console.

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]` can be replaced by `document.head`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the time that those commands are entered into the console, `$` is not jQuery - rather, it is a *helper function* provided by the *browser* that is very similar to `document.querySelector`. See [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/The_command_line_interpreter#Helper_commands) on the built-in helper functions available on some browsers.

You can see the source for Firefox's `$` [here](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/devtools/server/actors/webconsole/utils.js):

```
WebConsoleCommands._registerOriginal("$", function(owner, selector) {
  try {
    return owner.window.document.querySelector(selector);
  } catch (err) {
    // Throw an error like `err` but that belongs to `owner.window`.
    throw new owner.window.DOMException(err.message, err.name);
  }
});
```

Even if `$` *were* jQuery, the line

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

wouldn't refer to jQuery yet, because you *only just* inserted the script - it hasn't necessarily been downloaded and parsed yet. So, it'll still refer to the `querySelector` alias, and

```
document.querySelector(document)
```

doesn't make any sense.

The best solution would be to attach a `load` handler to the inserted script, so that you can run a function once jQuery is loaded. For example:

```
const jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js";
document.head.appendChild(jq);
jq.addEventListener('load', () => {
  console.log("hello world");
  console.log($ === jQuery);
});
```

Once jQuery loads, it will ensure that `window.$` *now* points to `jQuery` rather than the `querySelector` alias; the above snippet will log `true` after a moment.